# Share ubuntu-server 16.04 folder to windows host

Tags: server, samba

I have installed the ubuntu-server 16.04 and VBoxLinuxadditions and Samba

I am trying to share a folder from this server to my windows host machine.
Now I can see this virtual server on my network but there are no shared folders on the server.

[image]

How do I make one through the command line?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/877464/29012) has a very easy to follow step by step command line setup.

Comment: TNX i will check that out now

Comment: Extremely easy if you manually install samba and ?-share if the system fails to install them automatically. See my answer below.

Comment: I am using above commands to share folders from ubuntu to windows.
It works gracefully.
But there is a problem, It times out after a while.
Is there any way to add shared folders to samba configuration permanently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So i have figured this on my own and this is the easiest solution:

just install samba with

```
sudo apt install samba
```

and go to this file:

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and just at the bottom add these lines:

```
[share]

comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = /path/to/the/folder  #for example /home/user_name/public <- this comment needs to be deleted!
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

restart the samba service

```
sudo service smbd restart
sudo service nmbd restart
```

and that's it, easy peasy :)

Comment: What to do next? Where to find the shared folder from the client machine?

Comment: Just browse the network in Windows and it should be there after restart.

Comment: didn't work... using Ubuntu 16 LTS

Comment: I added /home folder as a [share]. After samba restart, I indeed see the "share" folder in Network \\myBuntuServer but when I try to open it, I get "Windows cannot access \\myBuntuServer\share. The network name cannot be found".  I found why - the first is, you cannot leave the # comments in the line with the folder name and the second is - the folder you share with `guest ok` should have anonymous permissions set ( 777 )

Comment: I question the use of "easy peasy" to describe Samba.

Comment: See also `force user`: https://askubuntu.com/a/206064/11522

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to share folders with SMB is

depending on the file manager you use, make sure nautilus-share or caja-share or ?-share is installed to enable next step

right-click on the folder and select the [Properties ->] Share tab that the file manager should provide

if that step doesn't propose to do it, install samba manually

choose the right sharing options and click Share

see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide#Ubuntu_Server

Answer (score 0):

To add a share that is accessible by all users.

Create the directory for sharing the files and change the owner to the users group.

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/samba/
sudo chown -R root:users /srv/samba/  [brusgroup][financial]
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx,o+rx-w /srv/samba/
```

---

Adding and managing users

eg. for group `users` and user `mattu`:

```
useradd mattu -m -G users
passwd mattu
sudo usermod -aG users mattu
```

Set a password for mattu

```
passwd mattu
```

Enter the password for the new user

---

Now add the user to the Samba user database.

```
sudo smbpasswd -a mattu
```

Enter the password for the new user

---

Edit the /etc/samba/smb.conf file

```
sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

add the following lines and save the file

```
[allusers]
 comment = All Users
 path = /srv/samba/allusers/
 valid users = @users
 force group = users
 create mask = 0660
 directory mask = 0771
 writable = yes
```

If all users shall be able to read and write to their home directories via Samba, edit the /etc/samba/smb.conf file and remove all lines. In vim:

1. Type `gg` to move the cursor to the first line of the file, if it is not already there.
2. Type `dG` to delete all the lines.

Now you should be able to log in from your Windows workstation with the file explorer using username ruchi and the chosen password and store files on the ubuntu server either in ruchi's home directory or in the public shared directory.

```
[global] 
workgroup = WORKGROUP
#netbios name = [FRODO] 
passdb backend = tdbsam 
printcap name = cups 

add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -m %u 
delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel -r %u 
add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd %g 
delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel %g 
add user to group script = /usr/sbin/groupmod -A %u %g 
delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/groupmod -R %u %g 
add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/lib/nobody %u 

# Note: The following specifies the default logon script. 
# Per user logon scripts can be specified in the user account using pdbedit  
logon script = scripts\logon.bat 
# This sets the default profile path. Set per user paths with pdbedit 
logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%U 
logon drive = H: 
logon home = \\%L\%U 
domain logons = Yes 
os level = 35 
preferred master = Yes 
domain master = Yes 

#[deprecated thus change
#idmap uid = 15000-20000 
#idmap gid = 15000-20000 
#]
#[ 
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 10001-20000
idmap config DOMAIN : backend = rid
idmap config DOMAIN : range = 10000-20000
idmap config DOMAIN : base_rid = 0 
#]
printing = cups 


Example 2.8. Engineering Office smb.conf (shares and services)



[homes] 
comment = Home Directories 
valid users = %S 
read only = No 
browseable = No 
# Printing auto-share (makes printers available thru CUPS) 

[printers] 
comment = All Printers 
path = /var/spool/samba 
printer admin = root, maryo 
create mask = 0600 
guest ok = Yes 
printable = Yes 
browseable = No 

[print$] 
comment = Printer Drivers Share 
path = /var/lib/samba/drivers 
write list = maryo, root 
printer admin = maryo, root 
# Needed to support domain logons 

[netlogon] 
comment = Network Logon Service 
path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon 
admin users = root, maryo 
guest ok = Yes 
browseable = No 
# For profiles to work, create a user directory under the path 
# shown. i.e., mkdir -p /var/lib/samba/profiles/maryo 

[Profiles] 
comment = Roaming Profile Share 
path = /var/lib/samba/profiles 
read only = No 
profile acls = Yes
```